# How to change script execution location in vs-code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I want to run my Python project on my globally installed Python interpreter.

I don't want to be in the "Mosh Python Standard Library" virtual environment anymore but I can't figure out how to exit it.

This what is shown in my output window in VS Code:

[image: This what is shown in my output window in VS Code]

Here is a picture of my VS code terminal, the `venv` doesn't appear to be active:

[image: Here is a picture of my VS code terminal]

Sorry for any confusion in my post, I am new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the vs-code's command pallet and type in `Python: Selected Interpreter`. This will open a window which you can choose which interpreter you want your python files to debug. Or you can click on the bottom left corner's button and it will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my default python interpreter in settings.json was pointing to the virtual environment, so even though I selected the global interpreter in the bottom left it would still run on the unwanted venv